# Is it possible to remove URL in popup

Tags: ios, popup, alert

I have an application where I have used javascript alert popup box.

When I open that in smart device like iPhone then it shows the URL on top as shown below:

[image: popup]

So is there a way to remove that URL.?

Answer (score 0):

If you could find a way to set the delegate of that UIAlertView you can try to use

> - (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView

You can then change the title from there if this would work.